# MPMoviePlayerController shows only a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm attempting to have a video play directly after the launch screen shows however all I see if a black screen with the status bar showing at the top. At the moment this is all the app does so there's nothing else going on as far as I know that should stop the video playing.

The video plays on the iPad with no problems otherwise, seems to be in the correct format and so on. I'm targeting iOS 7 and I've tried using a different video and also tried using MPMoviePlayerViewController instead. All end up with the same result.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IntroMovie" withExtension:@"mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.window addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    [moviePlayer play];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in resource name (remember it's case sensitive) ? Can you NSLog movieURL ?

Comment: Also is it all you have in your AppDelegate ? Where window is created ?

Comment: The movieURL looks correct, no typos in the resource name. Also I did have a window being created, but removed that as there was mention of one not being needed for that controller.

Comment: I'm seeing now that the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification never occurs so it seems that the movie just doesn't even play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create MPMoviePlayerViewController object and not the former one.The playMovie method should be called after makeKeyAndVisible.If it still doesnt work try adding breakpoints and check if the URL for the given video is correct or not and if it has been added to the Copy Bundle resources.Hope this helps

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self playMovie];
    return YES;
}


-(void)playMovie
{
    NSURL *movieURL;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if(bundle != nil)
    {
        NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v"];
        if (moviePath)
        {
            movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

        }
    }


    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.viewController presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO completion:^{

    }];
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];




}
```

Comment: Don't suppose you know how to stop the flicking from a transition between the loading png and the video playing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no typos and correct project settings the only problem you might have is inside a codec that was used to create "mov" file. Try with some other mov files or try putting your mov file into phone library and try playing it from there

Comment: I've tried another movie I know works on the iPad and that didn't play either so I wasn't sure that would be an issue. The file I tried was an m4v file.

Comment: GREAT TIP ... the extensions can be a problem, and actually cause a crash.  Dec 2013 ..  it is hugely flakey about file name extensions (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard.  Bizarre.  Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes.  Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken.